# Create a variable from content in a matrix field

Tags: matrix

I want to create a variable based on the contents of a matrix block.  This is the code I created:

```
{% for item in entry.screenshot %} //my matrix field
    {% for asset in item.webpage %} // an asset field in the block
        {% set backgroundUrl = asset.url %} //want to declare a variable using the asset url
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This throws a "backgroundUrl not defined" error when I try to use the variable.  Obviously my syntax is wrong.  Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

This is a [twig thing](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html). Loops in twig are scoped. Variables defined in a loop cannot be used outside of that loop. To fix this, you simply have to declare the variable before the loop:

```
{% set backgroundUrl = "" %}
{% for item in entry.screenshot %}
    {% for asset in item.webpage %}
        {% set backgroundUrl = asset.url %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you know that you only have one asset you can shorten it a bit with:

```
{% set backgroundUrl = "" %}
{% for item in entry.screenshot %}
    {% set backgroundUrl = item.webpage.first().url %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, Bryan Redeagle!  It did seem like a scope issue, but did not know it was a Twig issue.  Much appreciated!

Comment: You can shorten it even further with just this: `{% set backgroundUrl = entry.screenshot[0].webpage.first().url %}`. If that field is not a required field then I'd drop a conditional around it as well: this: `{% set backgroundUrl = entry.screenshot | length ? entry.screenshot[0].webpage.first().url : 'no screenshot!' %}`